# I Don't want to wait for whole page to be loaded while automating browser using selenium and Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, vba7

Iam Trying to automate Google Chrome using Excel VBA and Selenium

But the website Iam using for accessing data loads a lot of ads before fully loading!
[Data Website Link](https://results.indiaresults.com/hp/himtu/result3/mquery.aspx?id=1800264384)

The element required for triggering for next command is present even before 1 sec of  full page loading.
But the Code waits for the page to be loaded fully before triggering the next command.(the whole page takes almost 7-8 seconds to load).

The elements in red box are what I really need. But the Code waits for loading all the stuff like ads and any unwanted scripts

[image: the elements in red box are what I really need. But the Code waits for loading all the stuff like ads and any unwanted scripts]

How can I Change the waiting time so that it does not wait for loading the full content.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just test for the presence of the item? Only used Selenium with C#, but think something along lines of.

```
Do 
    set el = driver.getelementbyid("idfoo")
    'few milisecond wait here not bad idea
Loop Until not El is nothing
```